# Describe and sketch the points that satisfy $x + y + z = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> The equation x + y + z = 1 describes some collection of points in R3. Describe and sketch the points that satisfy $x + y + z = 1$ and are in the x-y plane, in the x-z plane, and in the y-z plane.

Is my approach correct?

x-y plane: $(1,y,0)$,$(x,1,0)$

x-z plane: $(1,0,z)$,$(x,0,1)$

y-z plane: $(0,1,z)$,$(0,y,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $xy$-plane is where $z=0$. This means that $x+y+z=1$ becomes $x+y=1$, which is a diagonal line passing through $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$.

Your description is wrong, since $(1,y,0)$, for instance, implies that $y$ can take any value, when in fact it only satisfies $x+y+z=1$ for a single value of $y$.

---

Edit: Here's a picture showing the set $x+y+z=1$ (it's a plane extending in every direction, but that's hard to depict, so I shaded in the region in the positive octant) as well as the lines in the three planes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got it!  So for the x-y plane it would be $(1,0,0)$,$(0,1,0)$.  For the x-z plane it would be $(1,0,0)$,$(0,0,1)$ and finally the y-z $(0,1,0)$,$(0,0,1)$

Comment: @inquisitor Almost! It isn't enough, though, to list only $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ for the $xy$-plane, because there are other points in that plane that also satisfy the equation. For instance: $(\frac12, \frac12, 0), (\frac14,\frac34,0), (100,-99,0)$, etc. That's why it's better to describe the solution as the *line passing through* any two of those points. Above, I called it the "line passing through $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$", but it would be just as correct to refer to "the line passing through $(2,-1,0)$ and $(3,-2,0)$", for instance.

Comment: So is it correct to say the x-y plane is $(x,y,0),(x,y,0)$, the x-z plane is $(x,0,z)$,$(x,0,z)$ and the y-z plane is $(0,y,z),(0,y,z)$?

Comment: @inquisitor In general, you could describe the $xy$-plane as the set $\{(x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb R\}$. That's the whole plane, which is what is implied when you write more briefly $(x,y,0)$ without any further restriction. So yes, if you meant to refer to the whole plane, you could use $(x,y,0)$ as a shorthand. (Although I notice you wrote it twice, $(x,y,0), (x,y,0)$—why?) For the problem in question, the set of points satisfying $x+y+z=1$ that lie in the $xy$-plane is $\{(x,y,0) : x+y=1, x,y \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: I got it!  I'm too rigid in my approach and trying to use information learned only in the section I just studied.  I remember the notation you used in my discrete math class.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @inquisitor You're welcome! I'm adding a picture too in case it helps. (Forgive my rudimentary drawing skills.)